# MySQL equivalent of SQL Server FOR XML PATH

Tags: php, mysql

I am recently working this system with sql server, now i would like to swith with mysql for some reason. Ive got stuck in converting this line of codes to fit with mysql.. can someone give me a hand with this. here's the code:

```
 $sql = "
select t1.request_id,t1.user_id,t1.user_name,t1.dept_desc,t1.DivisionCode,t1.status,t1.remarks,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ',* '+convert(varchar(50),asd.technical_id)+'***'+convert(varchar(50),asd.category_id)+'***'+ asd.technical_desc
    FROM requesttechnical_tbl t2,technical_tbl asd
    WHERE t2.request_id = t1.request_id and asd.technical_id=t2.technical_id order by asd.category_id desc
    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS technical_desc,
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff sorry for that, I think the 'GROUP_CONCAT' function is what im looking but i dont know how to use it so far.

Comment: i would like to concatenate the technical id and category as technical description, as well as the name.

Comment: That's one heck of a query. Can you break that down into something simpler that's still representative of the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @tadman HERE SIR... select t1.request_id,t1.user_id,t1.user_name,t1.dept_desc,t1.DivisionCode,t1.status,t1.remarks,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ',* '+convert(varchar(50),asd.technical_id)+'***'+convert(varchar(50),asd.category_id)+'***'+ asd.technical_desc
    FROM requesttechnical_tbl t2,technical_tbl asd
    WHERE t2.request_id = t1.request_id and asd.technical_id=t2.technical_id order by asd.category_id desc
    FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS technical_desc

Comment: @tadman I would like to concatenate those columns inside the stuff() as one in technical_des, sorry for that. :-)

Comment: Less caps-lock, please. Please! If you have any code amendments, just edit your question. Code in a comment is really hard to make sense of.

Comment: @tadman done sir..

Comment: @tadman i believe i need to use the group_concat, but so far I dont know how to use it. i hope you can help with this.